# Unfinished basement in Georgia townhome; would vapor barrier on interior trap moisture?

Tags: insulation, basement, moisture, vapor-barrier

I have a town house that is a middle unit on a slab. The back wall is above grade, with exterior windows and door.  The sidewalls abut adjacent units, ***so there is no wall in contact with soil for the area in question.***

One room is finished.  Another is unfinished with 10' ceilings, exposed 6" studs and fiberglass insulation.  The insulation is Kraft faced on the outside. The walls have OSB sheathing, and on the exterior wall there is (I think) Tyvec wrap then brick veneer.

I want to use the unfinished area for projects and would like a barrier to keep glass wool and dust from raining down.

Would 6mil clear plastic barrier create moisture issues?  If so, what's a better choice for easy and inexpensive dust protection for a space with exposed fiberglass insulation?